# how to count the result of stored procedure

Tags: mysql

Tthe procedure is working properly. What I need is to row count the result of procedure.

```
DROP PROCEDURE `tradematch`//
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `tradematch`(IN `pid` INT)
BEGIN 
SELECT p.company_name,p.company_info,pc.contact_address,pc.mobilenumber,p.idprofile,b.businesstype 
FROM profile p,profile_contact pc,businesstypelkp b 
WHERE p.idprofile=pc.idprofile_contact 
AND p.business_type=b.idbusinessTypeLKP 
AND p.idprofile not in (SELECT p.idprofile FROM profile p WHERE FIND_IN_SET(idprofile,(select Group_Concat(member_list) as group_members from groupmemberlkp where profile_id=pid))) AND FIND_IN_SET(idprofile,(SELECT group_concat(p.profileid) from products_profile p where FIND_IN_SET(product_id,(SELECT group_concat(product_id) FROM `rawmaterial_profile` WHERE profileid=pid))AND p.profileid!=pid));
END//
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an `OUT` parameter and the SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS <--> FOUND_ROWS() combo. You can read more about it [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows).

```
DROP PROCEDURE `tradematch`//
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `tradematch`(IN `pid` INT, OUT result INT)
BEGIN 
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS p.company_name,p.company_info,pc.contact_address,pc.mobilenumber,p.idprofile,b.businesstype 
FROM profile p,profile_contact pc,businesstypelkp b 
WHERE p.idprofile=pc.idprofile_contact 
AND p.business_type=b.idbusinessTypeLKP 
AND p.idprofile not in (SELECT p.idprofile FROM profile p WHERE FIND_IN_SET(idprofile,(select Group_Concat(member_list) as group_members from groupmemberlkp where profile_id=pid))) AND FIND_IN_SET(idprofile,(SELECT group_concat(p.profileid) from products_profile p where FIND_IN_SET(product_id,(SELECT group_concat(product_id) FROM `rawmaterial_profile` WHERE profileid=pid))AND p.profileid!=pid));

SET result:=FOUND_ROWS();

END//
```

Then when you execute the query:

```
CALL yourProcedure(yourId, @whatever);
SELECT @whatever;
```

This way the procedure displays the result and with the second `SELECT` you get the row count. If you don't need to display the result of the query, the question is, if you need the stored procedure at all.